# How wordpress retrieves user info?

Tags: users

The WordPress function `wp_get_current_user()` uses the global variable `$current_user` to get the get current logged-in user info.

What I would like to know is, how does WordPress retrieve the data from session cookie and store it in this global variable (`$current_user`).

Thank you for you help!!

Comment: WordPress doesn't use session to store current user, it uses [Cookies](https://wordpress.org/support/article/cookies/).

Comment: The cookie 'wordpress_logged_in_*' is used for this purpose right? If so, then how does wordpress get the current user info from this cookie.

Comment: The source says all: [`_wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_get_current_user/) and [`WP_User`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) class

Comment: Well it's really wp_validate_logged_in_auth_cookie and wp_validate_auth_cookie, which takes the username and session token (amongst other things) from the cookie and then validates the session token against the user's session_token user meta.